# What is a good metric for a binary classifier when we are more interested in Precision than Recall but care about confidence scores?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-data, goodness-of-fit, model-evaluation

I have an heavily imbalanced dataset and am training a binary classifier (which produces scores in the range 0 to 1) and need a single summary metric to tune hyperparameters with.

For my problem, precision is maybe 3X more important than recall. One option would be to use an F-score weighted towards precision, but I am keen to incorporate the model scores rather than using a hard cutoff for the decision function.

One popular option in this case seems to be to plot a Precision-Recall Curve and then find the area under it (mAP). This deals with the class imbalance and uses the scores coming out of the model which is great, but I think it gives equal weight to precision and recall which is not ideal.

Comment: I don’t see a way to have precision or recall without having a hard cutoff. Precision and recall have to do with classification, and classification requires a decision about the class to which the input belongs.

Comment: Sorry yes what I mean by this is that methods like mAP scan across many hard thresholds allowing us to take into account the fact that the model's real world use cannot always be well measured by taking the default cutoff of 0.5. It might just be that raising the threshold to 0.8 gives the model the desired precision-recall balance needed, and using a metric like mAP which scans all thresholds would allow such a model to show its quality. Problem with mAP seems to be that it gives equal weight to recall and precision though.